# Using imagick montageImage PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, montage

I'd like to use imagemagick to make a montage from existing photos on my server. I am having a terrible time getting any code to work properly. I've tried using the few examples I've found by searching, but it's not working.

https://www.php.net/imagick outlines the library beautifully, but there are no montage examples. I'd just need a proper example to get me off on the right foot and I' can usually take it from there.

Does anyone know of a good resource to learn imagick for PHP?

Comment: Do you want Imagemagick?  Or would javascript be more appropriate?

Comment: I didn't know JS was capable of cropping, resizing, stitching together images and placing a border around them.

Comment: Umm yeah you can do all of that in javascript to an extent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [working example of montageImage](https://web.archive.org/web/20100612225933/http://valokuva.org/?p=72). The example does a color analysis of a photo. To make sure it works properly, you will need to make sure:

1. You have a valid "test.png".
2. Imagick::clone has been deprecated as of imagick 3.1.0 in favour of using the clone keyword. So if you have imagick 3.1.0, you will need to change lines 13 and 17.

   $bright = $average->clone();

to

```
$bright = clone $average;
```

and

```
$dark = $average->clone();
```

to

```
$dark = clone $average;
```

Good luck.

Answer (score -2):

Did you start with the basic example?

```
http://us1.php.net/manual/en/imagick.examples-1.php
```

Comment: Yes I've played with all of those. montageImage has no examples tho.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood what a photo montage was.  I was thinking slide show.  However searching google produced a number of websites with examples of how to use montageImage.